# Weird output of python division

Tags: python, division

I have this function

```
def getXVals(maxVal = 100):
    listt = []
    i = 1
    while i != 11:
        listt.append(float(maxVal/i))
        i += 1
```

which is returning

```
[100.0, 50.0, 33.333333333333336, 25.0, 20.0, 16.666666666666668, 14.285714285714286, 12.5, 11.11111111111111, 10.0]
```

and I want it to return even intervals. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're returning `100/1, 100/2, 100/3`, etc.  What do you want it to return?

Comment: x/1, x/2, x/3, x/4 are not all even intervals across x. What you actually want is 1*x/10, 2*x/10, 3*x/10, etc.

Comment: what... it's a math problem. it will output the same thing regardless of the language you use. think about it, why it's not even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximately everything. If you want a linear interpolation from 0 to x with n steps then you need to multiply x by k/n where k goes from 0 to n. You... don't do this.

```
[maxVal * k / 10 for k in range(0, 11)]
```

Comment: `range(0, 11)`? how about `range(11)` :)

Comment: @Amber: Sure. It's obvious what needs to be changed if you want it to start at 1 instead (although that 11 is pretty nasty).

Comment: then just use `range(10,0,-1)` ;)

Comment: This won't work the same in Python 2 as 3 because of the integer division and it doesn't explicitly say Python 2 or 3 anywhere in this Q&A.